# Какие хуки и фильтры есть в админке wordpress у произвольных типов записей?

Tags: wordpress, hook

Возникла необходимость внести свои визуальные коррективны в кастомный тип записей в вордпрессе. Именно в админке. Интересует список элементов произвольных типов записей, а также страница редактирования такой записи.

Я полагаю, что там наверняка должны быть хуки, которыми можно манипулировать через functions.php, и если есть, то какие? Может есть плагины по типу "woocommerce hooks", которые позволяют увидеть все хуки в админке? Или есть иные способы, с помощью которых можно вносить свои изменения во внешний вид и функционал страницы редактирования элемента произвольного типа записей, а также список в админке такого типа записей?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Хуки стандартные для всех типов записей. Сами "элементы" я так предполагаю, для Вас это метабоксы. Кроме стандартных могут быть кастомные созданные администратором, их хуки и обработчики нужно смотреть в коде. Также, хорошо бы знать, чем создавали кастомный пост тип(плагином или через код).

Comment: Хуков очень много, их перечисление займёт много времени. Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос

Comment: Тип создавал плагином, при необходимости могу кодом, просто лень возиться было с иконкой.

Comment: Допустим, у меня кодом создаются элементы у этого типа записей, и там есть мета-поля. Я хочу чтобы информация в этих метаполях показывалась в формате html для админа, вписать туда свой интерфейс.